# Can I use the VSE to append multiple strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Can the video sequence editor be used to add several image sequences together, on top of each other?

Here's how I'd do it outside of Blender with Imagemagick in a bash loop:

```
for f in render1/*png; do
    frame=$(basename $frame)
    convert -append render1/$frame render2/$frame ./stitched/$frame
done
```

...then import the frames from `stitched` into the sequencer.

Would take two frames like these:

[image]

[image]

And turn them into this:

[image]

Can the equivalent operation be done directly in the VSE?

Comment: Are you trying to create something like a film strip? If so, there is a modified version of the Import Images as Planes that stacks up images in a  predetermined axis.

Comment: I just want to have multiple videos stacked on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! My result from just the VSE is the following. Note that you could use the same method for movie strips.

[image]

The first thing that you will have to do is adjust the dimensions to make sure there is no distortion in the *Properties panel > Render tab > Dimensions dropdown > Resolution: settings*.

*With two 1080p images, one might use these Dimensions:*

[image]

In the VSE, you can add two image strips on top of each other and then add an *Effect Strip > Transform* to each by selecting one, keying <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Effect Strip > Transform* and repeating for the other one. Make sure that whichever *Transform* strip is on top has *Alpha Over* set in the *VSE Properties Panel > Edit Strip dropdown > Blend: selection*. This is what my strips look like in the VSE:

[image]

Whichever image you want to show on top should use these *Transform strip > VSE Properties panel > Effect Strip dropdown* settings:

[image]

Whichever image you want to show on bottom should use these *Transform strip > VSE Properties panel > Effect Strip dropdown* settings:

[image]

Here is a .blend for reference:

[image]

Comment: Do you think there'd be a way to "rig" this setup to make it easy to add a 3rd (or 4th..) strip to the mix? Right now this would require doing the math, and 1) update render dimensions, 2) update Transformation strip's `y` position and scale, 3) adding the new strip(s) with transformations and appropriate settings.

Comment: @ajwood Your correct with the math. The one step your missing is that all _Transform_ strips except the bottom one would have to have _Alpha Over_ enabled. Did my answer help? Can I make it better?

Comment: As long as the images are the same dimensions, you could make the Transform effects apply to Metastrips. The you could easily change the contents of the metastrips without deleting and re-adding the transform effect. You could stack lots of these metastrip transforms, then in the preview window only view the number in the stack you want. Simply multiply height by number of transform effect strips.

Comment: In an ideal world, I could imagine a single-step where you "add new strip to stack" that would take care of all the math, since these values are just a function of the number of strips on the stack. Doesn't seem like the mechanics exist to make that possible though...